# How can I grant all postgres permissions to my local user?

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions

Trying to run various database commands, I got a lot of errors from postgres:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create database
ERROR: permission denied to create extension "hstore"
```

etc...

I can run them as the postgres user but this is annoying and finicky and will have to be repeated anytime i make a database operation.  How to grant all permissions to a given user?

Answer (score 1):

the following line worked to grant all permissions to my user:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER <username> SUPERUSER"
```

adapted from [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/463B31D5.8040308@archonet.com)